# mounting davfs2 not responding on debian

Tags: debian, mount, webdav, davfs2

I have a debian server with a davfs2 mounted. but a few days the mounting is not working.

I confirmed the fstab and secret file, this files are correct and nothing was changed.

when running the mount /mnt/webdisk not connect and not show error:

Tks

[image: mounting davfs2]

[image: iptables]

Comment: Check the remote server.

Comment: the remote server is ok, I logged in the same login / password in the browser. But even though if was the remote server had a problem, would must show an error, isnt ?

Comment: Is it firewalled, then?

Comment: no rules on iptables. The funny thing is that it works for a year, the problem started in 02/20. I updated the question with print.